# Querying Child Collections 2 levels deep in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-entities

i currently have a linq to entities model set up as follows

each Sample has a collection Of Tests
each Test has a collection of Results 
Each Result has Status property valuing whether it is Available or Completed

how would i write a linq query that would: 
get the samples that have available Results
retaining only the tests that have available results 
and only the results in each test  that are available

having trouble getting my head around this problem and help with getting this 
written would really help alot

Classes:

```
public class Sample
{
    public Sample()
    {
        Tests = new List<Test>();
    }

    public          int                     Id              { get; set; }
    public          string                  IdText          { get; set; }
    public          DateTime                SampleDate      { get; set; }
    public          DateTime                LoginDate       { get; set; }
    public          string                  Container       { get; set; }
    public          string                  Product         { get; set; }
    public          string                  Name            { get; set; }
    public          string                  Status          { get; set; }

    public virtual  SamplePoint SamplingPoint { get; set; }
    public virtual  SampleTemplate SampleTemplate { get; set; }
    public virtual  Customer ForCustomer { get; set; }
    public virtual  ICollection<Test> Tests { get; set; }

public class Test
{

    public Test()
    {
        Results = new List<Result>();
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Analysis { get; set; }
    public string ComponentList { get; set; }
    public virtual Instrument InstrumentUsed { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Result> Results { get; set; }
    public virtual Sample ForSample { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string TestNumber { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Analysis { get; set; }
    public string ComponentName { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Units { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public int OutOfRange { get; set; }
    public DateTime SampledDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime SampleLoginDate { get; set; }
    public string SamplePoint { get; set; }
    public virtual Sample ForSample { get; set; }
    public virtual Test ForTest { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If I understand your table structure then it's fairly easy to query down to get the results that you're interested in.

I put together a simple set of classes to test the results.

```
public static class db
{
    public static List<Sample> Samples = new List<Sample>();
}

public class Sample
{
    public string Name;
    public List<Test> Tests = new List<Test>();
}

public class Test
{
    public string Name;
    public List<Result> Results = new List<Result>();
}

public class Result
{
    public string Name;
    public string Status;   
}
```

And I created this set of test data:

[image: Test Data]

From here it is easy to query the data down to just available results:

```
var query =
    from s in db.Samples
    from t in s.Tests
    from r in t.Results
    where r.Status == "Available"
    select new { Sample = s.Name, Test = t.Name, Result = r };
```

Which gives me this data:

[image: Bad Data]

But that doesn't group the data by Sample and Test properly.

One way to do it properly is to create new `Sample` & `Test` objects that contain only the available results, like so:

```
var query =
    from s in db.Samples
    from rt in (
        from t in s.Tests
        from r in t.Results
        where r.Status == "Available"
        group r by t into rts
        select new Test()
        {
            Name = rts.Key.Name,
            Results = rts.ToList()
        })
    group rt by s into srts
    select new Sample()
    {
        Name = srts.Key.Name,
        Tests = srts.ToList()
    };
```

This produces this result:

[image: New Data]

However, it might not be possible, or desirable, to create new instance of objects that look like actual entities but are not actually from the database. It might be possible to accidentally persist one of these objects back to the database and wipe out correct records!

So, an alternative, which I think is the best, is to create a nested structure that contains the unmodified database entities and includes the available tests in an extra properly all while keeping the nested structure!!

Here's how:

```
var query =
    from s in db.Samples
    from rt in
        (from t in s.Tests
        from r in t.Results
        where r.Status == "Available"
        group r by t into rts
        select new
        {
            Test = rts.Key,
            AvailableResults = rts.ToArray()
        })
    group rt by s into srts
    select new
    {
        Sample = srts.Key,
        AvailableTests = srts.ToArray()
    };
```

And this produces:

[image: Good Data]

With these results you still have access to the unchanged `Sample` and `Test` objects, but all filtered by the available results.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: i updated my posts with the classes so you can see my class structure

Comment: ps bonus if i can get it in fluent structure and no anonymous objects  all i want at the end is a List<Sample> with the right data attached to it

Comment: Based on your class structure my middle query would do what you want nicely. You just need to wire it up.

Comment: @AvidProgrammer - Are you asking me or the OP?

Comment: @Enigmativity - I was asking Chris, whether he was able to do this with entity framework? Sorry if it created confusion. But the answer is very helpful.

Comment: @AvidProgrammer - Then you need to include an @ ChrisMcGrath (no space between) in your message so that he gets notified. Without that he's very unlikely to ever see your message.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your actual class structure, I'm hoping this can help in some way:

```
var testsWithAvailableResults = from test in dbContext.Tests
                                    select new {
                                        Results = (from result in test.Results where result.Status == "Available")
                                     };
```

Comment: i need one level higher Tests are a child of sample